# ActionController::RoutingError No route matche

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

In my rails development environment I got this lots of error like this

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD]
>   "/assets/quick_view_img_5-1ad660d2c659e1c1c0240651f669583d3f74ec91152b4672ef043234891f873a@2x.jpg"):

I have notice all the image assets was appended with @2x that causes the error. When I tried to remove the @2x character in the file name the image can be found.

Why rails is appending @2x to all of my images? and how to remove this.

Comment: Are using `retinajs`?  It looks like this is expected behavior for this gem.

Comment: @steveklein your right but for me its not a gem. I have included retinajs in the javascript asset. Can you post the answer so that i can give you the points.

Comment: Thanks @Chris but I really don't understand exactly what is happening and don't want to leave an inaccurate answer.  Can you answer and accept?  Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Retina.js and Retina.min.js are responsible for this as @steveklein mentioned in the comment above.

This javascript script searches for high quality images on your server and  adds '@2x' at the end of the images name, just before the extensions name, if it finds one. So image.jpg becomes image@2x.jpg.

You either need to add an image called image@2x.jpg to your assets folder to display on Retina screens or don't include the Retina.js and Retina.min.js scripts at all.

Don't forget to do a `rake assets:clobber` and `rake assets:precompile` after you have removed the script from your assets folder.